# How to set Google application credentials in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-cloud-platform

I'm following Google's "[Using the client library](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries?authuser=1#client-libraries-usage-ruby)" and am trying to use the Google Cloud platform to upload images to a bucket I created on Google. I also created a service and dowloaded the JSON file localy to my project.

The JSON is located directly in my `config/` folder.

I also added the required gem for Google and am using the Figaro gem to handle enviroment variables.

I don't understand how to set the value of the environment variable to point to my JSON file which holds my service credentials.

This is my code in my POST action for my controller:

```
storage = Google::Cloud::Storage.new project_id: '******'
bucket  = storage.bucket '******'
bucket.create_file allowed_params["image"], storage_file_path
```

This is how I am trying to set `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` in my application.yml file:

```
GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS: *********-3d373986410c6.json
```

The file `application.yml` and my `*********-3d373986410c6.json` is located in the same folder/path.

The error I get is:

```
Could not load the default credentials. Browse to https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for more information
```

What am I missing?

Comment: What is the value for the environment variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`? Add a debug line in your code and verify the value.

Comment: It is nil but is set in the application.yml

Comment: What is the value when you check from inside your code? The error message indicates that you did not set the value correctly.

Comment: This post solved my issue
https://medium.com/@pjbelo/setting-up-rails-5-2-active-storage-using-google-cloud-storage-and-heroku-23df91e830f8

Comment: Could you add the comment as an answer?

Answer (score -3):

@webbie solved the issue himself as can be seen in the question comments.
Adding the comment as Community Wiki answer to improve the visibility of the solution:

"This post solved the issue https://medium.com/@pjbelo/setting-up-rails-5-2-active-storage-using-google-cloud-storage-and-heroku-23df91e830f8 "

Comment: In addition, please add the solution to your answer.

Comment: Don't link to resources behind a paywall please